# Firebase Analytics log errors Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, logging, swift3, firebase-analytics

I am getting the following error in Xcode. I have found a few other threads that mention it as a Firebase error, but adjusting the scheme (See image), is not getting rid of the error. Im concerned the app will not be accepted by the App Store

```
2017-04-24 18:04:58.568 MyAppName[0000] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2017-04-24 18:04:58.650 MyAppName[0000] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.3800000 started
2017-04-24 18:04:58.650 MyAppName[0000] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo .gl/RfcP7r)
2017-04-24 18:04:58.826 MyAppName[0000] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not Error messages. Just some notice messages to give you some information. The flags you add to the app just turn off the Debug messages. It has nothing to do with Apple accepting your app.